# Syntax in generic class

Tags: c++, templates, comparator

I trying to solve an exercice with templates.
My code is working well in most cases but I found one case which was not working, here is a part of my code.
The default comparator is <.

```
template <typename type1, typename typecomparator=less<typename type1::valuetype1> >
class Myclass
 {
   public:
   Myclass ( const type1 & arg1,const typecomparator & comparator = typecomparator () )
   {
    this->seq=arg1;
    this->comp=comparator;
   }
   ~Myclass ( void ){}
   // ...
   private:
    mutable type1 seq;
    typecomparator comp;
 };
```

The code is working is almost all cases.
exemple: `Myclass <string> test ( "abcabcabc" );`

But when I want to use a class:

```
class another
 {
   public:
                   another ( bool caseSensitive )
                    : m_CaseSensitive ( caseSensitive ) { }
    bool           operator () ( const string & a, const string & b ) const
     {
       return m_CaseSensitive ? strcasecmp ( a . c_str (), b . c_str () ) < 0 : a < b ;
     }
    bool           m_CaseSensitive;
 };

bool upperCaseCompare ( const char & a, const char & b )
 {
   return toupper ( a ) < toupper ( b );
 }
```

example:

```
Myclass <list<string>, another> t6 ( list<string>{"foo","done"}, another ( false )) ;
```

I get this error.

```
index.cpp: In constructor ‘Myclass<type1, typecomparator>::Myclass(const type1&, const typecomparator&) [with type1 = std::list<std::basic_string<char> >, typecomparator = another]’:
index.cpp:67:136:   instantiated from here
index.cpp:20:4: error: no matching function for call to ‘another::another()’
index.cpp:20:4: note: candidates are:
index.cpp:50:20: note: another::another(bool)
index.cpp:50:20: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided
index.cpp:47:7: note: constexpr another::another(const another&)
index.cpp:47:7: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided
index.cpp:47:7: note: constexpr another::another(another&&)
index.cpp:47:7: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided
```

I tried to rewrite the code but I don't understand how to solve this problem.

Comment: Why the default comporator is `less<typename type1::valuetype1>` but not `less< typename type1::value_type >` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that you do not use initialisation list in your constructor, so members of MyClass are fist constructed with their default constructor, and only then copied from the argument. Use

```
Myclass ( const type1 & arg1,const typecomparator & comparator = typecomparator () )
 : seq(arg1), comp(comparator)
{
}
```

and the default constructor of `another` should be no longer needed.

Answer (score 1):

default the assignment constructor

```
another ( const another&  ) = default;
```